# Running "screen" in terminal VS running "screen" as keybind?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

If I'm in a screen session and I run `screen` from the terminal, a new window opens up in the same directory as the previous window. However if I bind the `screen` command to a keybind, like this `bindkey "^[[1;5A" screen`, using the keybind results in a new window in the home directory instead of the current directory.

First of all, why is it like this?

Second, how do i open up a new window in the current directory through a keybind? I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517488/6224823) but that wouldn't work, since  it prints to the console and can't therefor be used while another program is running, ex webpack.

Comment: ...what is wrong with the proposed method `screen -X eval "chdir $PWD" `? or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282023/9224859) ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl it prints to the console

Comment: as always, the gold is in the comments: `bindkey ^f stuff "screen^M"` worked for me, using Ctrl-f.

Comment: @RobertRiedl That prints `screen` to the original console...

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot prohibit that "screen" is printed to the original window - sorry !